# xslt key and match

Tags: xslt

I am pretty new to xslt, sorry for the confusion i caused and may waste your time...
Actually what I am really trying to do is: I have two queries, 
first query (orders/order)

```
<query name="orders" rowElementName="order">
 select ordernumber, subtotal, total
 from tablex
</query>
```

return something like:

> ordernumber      subtotal    total
>      123              20          23.5
>      234              19          26.5

another query (orderitems/lineitem)

```
<query name="OrderItems" rowElementName="lineitem">
 select ordernumber, cartitemid, productname, sku
 from tabley
</query>
```

return something like:

> ordernumber    cartitemid  productname     sku
>      123             3           test1          s9sdidk
>      123             4           test2          s9sdidl
>      234             5           test3          s9sdidu
>      234             6           test4          s9sdidh

and then output like this (seperate two orders):

> Product      sku
>
> ---
>
> test1                                           s9sdidk
>      test2                                           s9sdidl
>
> ---
>
> ```
>      Subtotal:  20.00    
>      Total: 23.5
> ```
>
> Product      sku
>
> ---
>
> test3                                           s9sdidu
>      test4                                           s9sdidh
>
> ---
>
> ```
>      Subtotal:  19.00    
>      Total: 26.5
> ```

Comment: What does this have to do with XSLT? Seems more like a SQL question.

Comment: in my xslt, I use those two queries to get data, then display to the web page...I am still trying your solution. for some reason, the item didn't get displayed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xslt generator to sql code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327748/xslt-generator-to-sql-code)