# Xslt generator to sql code

Tags: asp.net, xslt

```
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/Update/Object/Insert">
  Insert into <xsl:value-of select="@Table" />(
  <xsl:for-each select="Field">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Name" />,      
  </xsl:for-each>)
  Values(
    <xsl:for-each select="Field">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Value" />,
    </xsl:for-each>)
</xsl:template>
```

**Output :**
Insert into Good(
      GoodCode,
      ...
      ,
      )
      Values(
        1,
        ...
        ,
        )

as you can see there is a extra "," the question is how I can correct it ?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='book.xslt'?>
<Update>
  <Object Name="Good">
    <Insert Table="Good">
      <Field Name="GoodCode" Value="1" Type="Integer" />
      <Field Name="GoodUserCode" Value="" Type="String" />
</insert>
</object>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use something like this:

```
 <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="/Update/Object/Insert">
      Insert into <xsl:value-of select="@Table" />(
   <xsl:for-each select="Field">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Name" /><xsl:if test = "position() != last()">, </xsl:if>      
   </xsl:for-each>)
   Values(
   <xsl:for-each select="Field">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Value" /><xsl:if test = "position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>)
 </xsl:template>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_if.asp